# Zapier code - await is only valid in async function

Tags: zapier, pendo

I'm trying to pull data from Hubspot into Pendo using Zapier code (a recommendation from my Pendo rep). When testing using the code below I get "Syntax error: await is only valid in async function".

I have researched and tried making an `async` `IIFE` but that also didn't work. So, I'm wondering if there is an error somewhere else in my code causing the error, or, is there a better way to approach this rather than using `await`?

````
const data = [{
  "accountId": inputData.body.accountId,
  "values": {
     "Became Customer": inputData.body.becameCustomer,
     "Total MRR": inputData.body.totalMRR,
     "Company Owner": inputData.body.companyOwner
   }
}];
function updateAccount (z, bundle) {
  const promise = await fetch("https://app.pendo.io/api/v1/metadata/account/agent/value",     {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {
      "content-type": "application/json",
      "x-pendo-integration-key": "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX.XX"}
    });
  return promise.then((response) => {
    if (response.status != 200) {
      throw new Error(`Unexpected status code ${response.status}`);
    } else {
      const content = JSON.parse(response.content);
      return content;
    }
  });
}
updateAccount()```
````

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping the function in async got rid of the error.

`const updateAccount = async function(z, bundle) {`